# Mobile connected to pc, and Windows asked for repair. Now, the "Camera" folder is gone and lost my 3 years photos

Tags: file-recovery, repair, mobile-phone

Today, I connected my Nokia 5230 mobile using data cable to PC, as Mass Storage Device. When connected, Window(win7) showed a popup saying that there are some issue with the device and asked me whether the OS shall do some repairs or not.

Since it's the first time that Windows was asking this, so I didn't wanted to make my OS feel unhappy :P 
So, I granted permission to do the repair.

After the repair, the `Camera` folder in my Memory Card has got converted into a single file! And I lost my 3 years of precious moments (photos)! I didn't got time to do backup of these photos all these years and all of a sudden, I have lost everything!

Is there any way to recover it? Any best tools particularly for this? I know there are lots of tools out there. But I don't want to try testing it one my one and make those photos permanently unrecoverable! :(

So any suggestions? I have attached the screenshot too.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That message means your filesystem was potentially corrupted, and in repairing it, `chkdsk` did a bad thing.

First, accept the fact that the photos might be totally gone. Now take a deep breath and we'll try to get them back...

In any case, avoid writing to your phone's memory card if possible. If this storage represents a removable SD card, take it out of the phone and connect it directly to your PC (if you have the appropriate card reader/cables).

Try an undelete tool like [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) - this will search the whole partition for deleted images. It may bring back things that you intentionally deleted, duplicates of some images, etc. The filename of the image is likely lost, but the tool will make one up for you. Again, don't *write* to the memory card - save the images to another place (a folder on your PC).

When you're done, I would recommend copying off the entire contents of the memory card, reformatting it, and then copying everything back. This will ensure that any corruption in the filesystem is entirely corrected and hopefully prevent this from reoccurring.